# Auto-cropping an image series as a whole (taking into account all images at once)

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

I have a series of images in PNG format that make up an animation.

I want to automate the process of cropping the excess transparency in the animation as a whole, so I need to find the unique smallest rectangular area such that, if every image were cropped to it, no opaque pixels would be trimmed from any image; then crop every image to this area.

IOW, the equivalent of making each PNG a layer in GIMP, doing "autocrop layer" on every layer, then "canvas size to layers", and reexporting every layer as a PNG again.

Is there a way to get mogrify or convert (or GIMP, for that matter, but I imagine in my case the number of images involved would take up too much memory to have them all as GIMP layers) to do this automatically?

If not, is there a scripting function that would return the autocrop rectangle for a given image, so I could check overlaps and find the smallest that would cover all of them, myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the cropping box for an image like this:

```
convert input.png -format "%@" info:
245x114+4+2
```

So, in this instance it is 245px wide by 114px tall and offset [4,2] from the top-left corner.

So, to test the theory, let's make 3 images with transparent background and little red boxes to represent your content. I have added a black border just so you can see the extent on Stack Overflow's white background:

```
convert -size 200x100 xc:none -fill red -draw "rectangle 10,10 20,20" 1.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 200x100 xc:none -fill red -draw "rectangle 180,20 190,30" 2.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 200x100 xc:none -fill red -draw "rectangle 150,80 160,90" 3.png
```

[image]

So, I can get the cropping box for all 3 images combined like this:

```
convert [123].png -evaluate-sequence mean -format %@ info:
181x81+10+10
```

And if I draw that on in blue:

```
convert result.png -stroke blue -fill none -draw "rectangle 10,10 191,91" -bordercolor black -border 1 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is great!  I thought I'd have to use PerlMagick or something.  With this I could script in any language just using the command-line output, definitely keeps the toolchain smaller for one's project.  :)